# HTML for system time to be populated in multiple columns of table

Tags: html

I am a beginner to HTML and have an issue where-in i am unable to populate the System time to multiple columns of a table at same time and the system date to Login Date. I want the System time to come as a drop-down option for Check-in and Check-out time columns and system date as fixed value in Login date simultaneously..., but as of now either one of them is only getting populated .

My code is given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function updateday()
                 {
                 var today = new Date();
                 var dd = today.getDate();
                 var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                 if(dd<10){
                 dd='0'+dd
                 } 
                 if(mm<10){
                 mm='0'+mm
                 } 
                 var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;                
                 setTimeout("updateday()",1000);
                 document.getElementById('day').innerHTML=today;
                 }
                 updateday();


   function updateTime() {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        if (minutes < 10){
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10){
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
        var v = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";
        if(hours > 11){
            v+="PM";
        } else {
            v+="AM"
        }
        setTimeout("updateTime()",1000);
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=v;
    }
    updateTime();

</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
       <div class="header" align="center">
          <h1 class="custom">TIME TRACKER</h1>
    </div>

<table id="list" border=1 cellspacing = "0px" cellpadding = "20px" text-align = "center">
               <tr>
                 <th>EMPLOYEE ID</th>
                 <th>EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
                 <th>CHECK-IN TIME</th>
                 <th>CHECK-OUT TIME</th>
                 <th>LOGIN DAY</th>
               </tr>         
              <tr>
               <td>
                    <select>
                           <option value=" ">------</option>
                           <option value="U16187">U16187</option>
                           <option value="U16188">U16188</option>
                           <option value="U16056">U16056</option>
                           <option value="C23456">C23456</option>
                           <option value="C12089">C12089</option>
                    </select>   
               <td>    
                    <select>
                           <option value=" ">------</option>
                           <option value="Samuel">Samuel</option>
                           <option value="Marlon">Marlon</option>
                        </select>
              </td>   
              <td>  
                   <select>
                          <option id="time" /> </option> 
                          <option value="blank" />(Blank)</option>  

                   <select>
              </td>
              <td>  
                  <select>
                         <option id="time" /> </option> 
                         <option value="blank" />(Blank)</option>  

                  <select>
              </td>
              <td><span id="day"</td>  

</table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code corrected and fixed. I made 2 seperate functions, and named the two option drop down different names. I think the issue was that the page was never running the second function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function updateday()
                 {
                 var today = new Date();
                 var dd = today.getDate();
                 var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                 if(dd<10){
                 dd='0'+dd
                 } 
                 if(mm<10){
                 mm='0'+mm
                 } 
                 var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;                
                 setTimeout("updateday()",1000);
                 document.getElementById('day').innerHTML=today;
                 }
                 updateday();

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function updateTime() {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        if (minutes < 10){
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        if (seconds < 10){
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
        var v = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";
        if(hours > 11){
            v+="PM";
        } else {
            v+="AM"
        }
        setTimeout("updateTime()",1000);
        document.getElementById('timeIn').innerHTML=v;
        document.getElementById('timeOut').innerHTML=v;
    }
    updateTime();

</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
       <div class="header" align="center">
          <h1 class="custom">TIME TRACKER</h1>
    </div>

<table id="list" border=1 cellspacing = "0px" cellpadding = "20px" text-align = "center">
               <tr>
                 <th>EMPLOYEE ID</th>
                 <th>EMPLOYEE NAME</th>
                 <th>CHECK-IN TIME</th>
                 <th>CHECK-OUT TIME</th>
                 <th>LOGIN DAY</th>
               </tr>         
              <tr>
               <td>
                    <select>
                           <option value=" ">------</option>
                           <option value="U16187">U16187</option>
                           <option value="U16188">U16188</option>
                           <option value="U16056">U16056</option>
                           <option value="C23456">C23456</option>
                           <option value="C12089">C12089</option>
                    </select>   
               <td>    
                    <select>
                           <option value=" ">------</option>
                           <option value="Samuel">Samuel</option>
                           <option value="Marlon">Marlon</option>
                        </select>
              </td>   
              <td>  
                   <select>
                          <option id="timeIn" /> </option> 
                          <option value="blank" />(Blank)</option>  

                   <select>
              </td>
              <td>  
                  <select>
                         <option id="timeOut" /> </option> 
                         <option value="blank" />(Blank)</option>  

                  <select>
              </td>
              <td><span id="day"</td>  

</table>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```